# Не показывать приложение в меню недавних приложений

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте не могли бы вы мне помочь. Я хочу, чтобы при сворачивании моего Андроид приложения оно исчезало из меню недавних. То есть активити работало, а приложения не было видно в меню недавно закрытых приложений. Закрывать полностью программу не нужно, только скрыть.

Ещё я пытался реализовать то, когда приложение закрывается с помощью жестов андроид, оно само закрывалось полностью, но у меня не выходит. То есть его не закрывали специально, а оно само закрывается, когда проводишь вверх по экрану с жестами андроид, и оно также исчезает из недавних программ. Пример: голосовой помощник от Xiaomi - MiAi

Comment: Как решите задачу можете отправлять запрос в Google на вознаграждение : ) Если приложение сворачивается, то оно отображается там, откуда Вы хотите его убрать. Может быть Вам нужен [фоновый режим](https://developer.android.com/guide/background)?

Comment: Просто например Google Assistant как-то исчезает из недавних. Вот я также как-то предполагал. Но если это невозможно, то ничего страшного.